# How long should one plan for visiting the Venice Biennale?

Tags: venice, artworks

I'm planing to visit this years [Biennale in Venice](http://www.labiennale.org/en/Home.html). How many days (and doing what?) would you suggest one should stay for seeing most of the exhibitions? I'm a regular visitor to the [Documenta in Kassel](http://www.documenta.de/) where I'm always planning for two packed days. Is the Biennale about the same size?